# Developing a simple CRUD App with Spring Boot and an existing Database

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to create a simple CRUD App using Spring Boot and an Existing Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [Spring Roo](https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/). Its entire purpose is to allow rapid application generation. There is also support for [reverse engineering an app from an existing database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html).

Version 2 will apparently also support Spring Boot, but I don't know if database reverse engineering already made it into v2. You could always try generating your application and adding Spring Boot later on.

I haven't much used it myself so unfortunately I can't offer you much guidance on its actual use - but you should be able to find some tutorials on Google, and StackOverflow contains several questions and answers on Spring Roo as well.

Comment: Apparently the whole reverse engineer feature was removed from version 2. Kind of a pointless app now.